# Dagger2 - singleton annotation issue

Tags: singleton, dagger

I have a problem with Dagger2 singleton annotation.
My module looks a bit like this:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    MyInterface provideSipManager(Context context) {
        Log.d("running provider");
        return new MyClass(context);
    }
}
```

Component is similar to:

```
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, MyModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Context context();
    void inject(MyApplication application);
    void inject(Myactivity1 myActivity);
    void inject(Myactivity2 myActivity);
}
```

The problem is that everytime I inject MyInterface, I get completely new object. I'm using Singleton annotation, so I should get the same instance. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you create a new component each time, or create one once and keep it around? The component instance keeps the state, so if you create a new component you'll necessarily create a new instance of each `@Singleton` you request.

Comment: Jeff Bowman You were right, the problem was creating App component multiple times. Thank you.